# Doctrine 2 - Bidirectional Self-referencing One to Many relation not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using the code below on my Model

```
    /**
 * Many Categories have One Category
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ItemCategory", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
public $parent;

/**
 * One Category has many Categories
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ItemCategory", mappedBy="parent")
 */
public $children;

/**
 * ItemCategory constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->parent_id = 0;
}

/**
 * @return ItemCategory
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $parent
 */
public function setParent($parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->children;
}
```

I am using this with Entity manager to get the repository and using findAll() to get all the results which are used on a controller that returns a json of the public properties.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Item\ItemCategory");
    $categories = $repository->findAll();
    return new JsonResponse(array("item_categories" => $categories));
```

Symfony is not throwing any errors, and the ManyToOne side is working without issues and pupulates the parent property with a full object.

The OneToMany side though remains empty no matter what I have tried.

The resulting array contains objects that look like that

`{
    "id": 8,
    "parent": {
        "id": 3,
        "parent": null,
        "children": {},
        "name": "Ανταλλακτικά",
        "description": "",
        "meta_description": "",
        "icon": "cogs"
    },
    "children": {},
    "name": "Ποδηλάτων",
    "description": "",
    "meta_description": "",
    "icon": ""
},`

I have searched a lot here on stackexchange and on the documentation, but I could find nothing that works.

I would appreciate a second look at my code in case I am missing something obvious. Thanks for your time

=========== UPDATE ==================

After some more investigation, it appears that the object returned for children is a PersistentCollection.
This means that I have to execute

$item->getChildren()->GetValues();

to get the actual children

Any thoughts on how I can avoid this and get the values directly on the property? Something to do with fetch mode set to EAGER perhaps?

Comment: Does `$parent->getChildren()` return a `DoctrineCollection` of items as expected?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have to execute 

$item->getChildren()->GetValues();

to get the array

Comment: That sounds like the problem; and unless I'm crazy, you'd want a `DoctrineCollection` instead of `array` returned from that getter...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The documentation states that it should return an ArrayCollection. Not sure how that defers from a DoctrineCollection.
The question is, where is the mistake on the annotation? Any ideas? thanks again for your time.

Comment: Annotations look okay to me, but I'm not an expert on that.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the getter for children to `return $this->children->toArray()` solve the problem?. See [Collection Interface](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html), also fetch eager might be needed to preload the children not sure if its required though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was lazy loading

Without changes to the model, you have to use

$item->getChildren()->GetValues();

Otherwise, you will have to experiment with annotating for eager loading

Answer (score 0):

ArrayCollection it helps to improve performance adding lazy loading, sorting and matching (both on the database if it has not been loaded the data  as well on the phpside if you already accessed to it).

Personally I really like working with ArrayCollection but you can just get rid off it updating your entity in the following way:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->children->toArray();
}
```

Filtering collections:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections